# Accessing file names from a file upload form using javascript

Tags: javascript

In the code below, how do I get the name of the file selected in the form so I can use the FileAPI to check it for size etc. There'll only be a single file, and a md5 key. I keep ending up with undefined in the script. I was following [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) on MDN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Upload File Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploadForm">
        <input type="file">
        <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="cb98a10429c5dabeb1a2b491a1a90b0a">
    </form>
    <button id="upload"><span>Upload</span></button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
(function(){

    checkFile = function() {
        console.log('Performing checks');

        formElements = document.getElementById('uploadForm');

        console.log(formElements);

        var files = formElements.files;

        console.log(files); //gives me undefined
    }

    document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click',checkFile);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `files` property belongs to the `<input>` element, not the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The id needs to be on the input field.

First in the javascript file change it to this:

```
(function(){

    checkFile = function() {
        console.log('Performing checks');

        let formElements = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
        const fileName = formElements.value.split("\\").pop();
        console.log(fileName);
        var files = formElements.files;

        console.log(files); //gives me undefined
    }

    document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click',checkFile);
})();
```

And you html to:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Upload File Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="uploadForm" type="file">
        <input type="hidden" name="handle">
    </form>
    <button id="upload"><span>Upload</span></button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>
</html>
```